# Variadic macros: Different output for identical code

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior, preprocessor

I've made a project in CLion to test macroes.
I created a macro to count the amout of arguments given to it.
Firstly this macro gave me valid output (0 for no args, 1 for one arg, 2 for two args ...).
But then, I don't know what happened, my macro just invalidated somehow. Maybe it was due to a lot of SIG_ILL failures, undefined behaviour when I called function from out of it's declaration scope, I declared function inside an expresion.

I was trying to implement methods and `new` operator like in C++, but via C preprocessor, which was ultimately successful until suddenly my macro for counting arguments failed.
It now gives 1 for no args, 1 for one arg, 2 for two args. And this error takes place when compiling, while still CLion's feature "inline current usage" shows me that this macro should expand to 0 when invoked with no args.

Here is this project, just simple main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Macro_argument_20(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, \
_11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, ...) _20

#define Macro_argumentsAmount(ARGS...) \
Macro_argument_20("dummy", ##ARGS, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11,10,\
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)

int main() {
    printf("%i", Macro_argumentsAmount());

    return 0;
}
```

I had no idea and created a new project to see what happens, so I copy/pasted previous CMakeLists.txt and code and got expected output.

So now I have two identical projects but with different output.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

UPD:

Still when inspecting preprocessed version of source code via

```
gcc -E main.c -std=c17  -fplan9-extensions  -Werror -Wno-implicit - 
Wno-error=variadic-macros -Wno-error=implicit-fallthrough
```

I see the following main in both projects (though one of them prints 0):

```
# 9 "main.c"
int main() {
 printf("%i", 1);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, so people can copy, paste, compile, run.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find option for hiding image. This problem seems unbelievable, so I wanted to give proofs.

Comment: Is `Macro_argumentsAmount()` zero arguments or is it one empty argument?  Why would you expect one over the other?  What result would you expect for `Macro_argumentsAmount(,)`?

Comment: @Chris, `Macro_argumentsAmount()` must expand to 0, that's how ## operator works when `ARGS` results in empty argument in such a context. As for `Macro_argumentsAmount(,)`, this should give 2, because you explicitly forward empty arguments to the macro, it just expands to a single coma, which implies habing two arguments on both of it's sides. Empty argument is also an argument. I coud've checked this issue by stringifying each argument and inquiring it's length, however such a forward seems too ridiculous and unnecessary for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure C"? `##ARGS` is a non-standard gcc extension, this code won't compile with a strict C compiler.

Comment: @Lundin extension implies "non-standard" by its definition, however I just wanted to emphasize this is not C++

Comment: @SimpliestOne: It is clear this is C from the tags and the code. I had added the GCC tag earlier, but I have edited away "Pure C" since it is a little misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `-std=c17` option to the compiler, you disable the GCC comma swallowing extension for `##ARGS`.

Use `-std=gnu17` instead to enable GNU extensions alongside c2017 features.

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed it, when playing with cmake compiler options, well thank you, that was very unexpected